# Sign of zeros of $\lambda^2+2\lambda+1-a+\frac{ar}{\delta}=0$ without explicit calculation

Tags: roots

I am interested in the zeros of this polynomial in $\lambda$:
$$\lambda^2+2\lambda+1-a+\frac{ar}{\delta}=0$$
where $0<a\leq1$, $r<0$ and $\delta>0$.
How to determine the sign of their real parts without explicit calculation?

Comment: It'll depend on the exact values , and there are two possibilities , either both negative or one negative and one positive . And also the roots are purely real

Comment: *Hint* : Vietta's theorem. But it should be mentioned that this is polynomial with respect to $\lambda$

Comment: @openspace: thank you, I edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sake of comfort, I will denote $\lambda$ by $z$. The equation is same as
$$(z+1)^2=a-\frac{ar}{\delta}$$Obviously, $a-\frac{ar}{\delta}\geq 0$, and hence, both the roots are real. Now, lets write the roots precisely,$$z_1:=-1+\sqrt{a-\frac{ar}{\delta}}\quad z_2:=-1-\sqrt{a-\frac{ar}{\delta}}$$Clearly, $z_2$ is negative. However, we can't comment on the sign of $z_2$ with the provided info. For instance, when $r=-1,\delta = 3, a=0.5$ we have $z_2<0$ and when $r=-6,\delta=2,a=0.5$ we have $z_2>0$.